# How to create a pivot table with sum matrix using javascript(jquery,native js)?

Tags: javascript

I want to get a result that will show a pivot table with matrix summation value from a json request. Example:

Business MajorBusiness Country Jan Feb Marc Total 
test 1   test 1        China      1   2    3    6 
 
test 2   test 1        China      2   2    2    6 
Total for China    =============  3   4    5    12 

Thanks in advance if someone can help me for my project.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a jQuery plugin called PivotTable.js: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable